# Why don't people seem to die from salmonella in bites?

Tags: zoology, pathology

As far as I know, reptiles have salmonella in their mouths as part of their digestive process. Every time I hear about someone being bitten by an python or alligator or monitor either at a zoo or in the news or from a private owner, it seems like whoever is bit recovers with ease.

How come something as virulent as salmonella that can evade an immune response doesn't cause whoever gets bitten to nearly immediately become septic? Is it because salmonella only attacks epithelial tissue and there isn't much of that deep in an arm or leg?

Comment: Important to considera as welk that a Salmonella infection isnt always that bad, even the gastrointestinal salmonella infection can be mild depending on the serotype. Salmonella is actually very common in some parts of the world and it isnt super deadly or anything.

Comment: @MikeKatz45 Others and myself been through enough food poisoning to know everything you just said is total BS.

Comment: nop, look at my answer

Comment: @MikeKatz45 I looked at the first few words and figured it was a waste of time and ignored the rest, especially considering the question is already answered. You can't speak against people's personal medical history and there is plenty of documentation that people have died from salmonella in the past. I am going to take a rare opportunity to downvote for the first time ever, congratz on being the only one to earn that.

Comment: Yes, those like you who make the mistake of assuming they are omnipotent gods. This is not a religion site, this is a biology site.

Comment: I provided all the sources to backup what I'm saying (which is relevant to responding the question because Salmonella doesn't always kill you or cause severe disease). The one who is being unreasonable is you and I haven't seen a single source to discuss this matter from your side, in that sense you are acting in a dogmatic way, not me. I commented this question because I thought it was a good question and that the answer given previously was oversimplified and I don't know why you took it like I was being an "omnipotent god" lol.

Comment: You arbitrarily mixed personal opinions with references, which doesn't change anything. If you want to go into denial over deaths across the globe, you have much bigger problems than this site.

Comment: What part exactly is a personal opinion? I never denied Salmonella can be as severe to kill you, I was only pointing out that it isn't as simple as saying Salmonella infection = dying or almost dying. The bacteria can cause a wide spectrum of things,  really don't get why you have this attitude when there is reason in all I said.

Comment: Not even ebola=dying, but that doesn't mean it isn't an enormous problem for whoever contracts it. Seeing as how that's true, your presence here has lead to no good, you clearly have no intention of contributing, you are only here for your own personal insecurities of your own intellect and nothing more. In far fewer words, Stephanie has accomplished what you failed to and without any emotional bickering, the topic is resolved and you have no purpose here.

Comment: In the case of salmonella yeah sometimes it isn't a problem at all cause you can be completely asymptomatic (as I have repeated until tireness now). I invite you to read this whole series of posts again and figure out *who* doesn't have the intention of contributing at all, you are the one who has been in a defensive position all the time (since you mentioned insecurities lol) . I won't make further posts here since you clearly have no interest in the question anymore whatsoever and it was all a waste of time for both you and me

Comment: Yet again you've proven my point. Whether or not it "can" be asymptomatic is regardless, the fact is that it isn't always and unless you have proof otherwise, you have no reason to be here. You are yet again reported for trolling.

Comment: Guys: First, please tone down. Then stop excessive commenting and move over to chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salmonella infect via the fecal-oral route. They have proteins on their surface that match our gut cell surfaces, allowing them to attach and invade the gut. Those cell markers aren't present when you are bitten. it's the same reason that plant virus dont make us sick.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17593246

this is a bit heavy if you dont usually read primary papers, but looking for "Salmonella route of infection" or similar will yield the same kind of information

Answer (score 1):

You can have *Salmonella* without actually knowing it, the reason behind this is that there is a group of salmonellas known clinically as non-typhoid Salmonellas (this means they are still *S: enteritidis*, but different serovars other than the more popular *S. typhi*). These most of the time cause mild infections as noted by the World Health Organization [non-typhoid Salmonella](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/salmonella-(non-typhoidal)). These infections can even be completely asymptomatic (carrier state) as it has been known for more than 2 decades [Old paper on treatment for asymptomatic salmonellosis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7640732). We also now know thanks to modern genomic analyses that even within different strains of *S. typhi* some strains are more virulent than others.

There is even an atlas provided regarding the "less popular" *Salmonella* serovars, I suggest checking it out if you are truly interested in this topic [CDC Salmonella Atlas](https://www.cdc.gov/salmonella/pdf/enteritidis-508c.pdf).

Also regarding your original question there is an useful review here that mentions human-infecting serovars of *Salmonella* reported in relationship with snakes & lizards [A Review of Salmonella and Squamates (Lizards, Snakes and Amphisbians): Implications for Public Health](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5617995/). As you will see the species reported belong to the group that can cause mild or asymptomatic infections so that could be contributing to the fact that people don't have that much trouble with bites from these animals in general. Of course what Stephanie said in his answer is true but also the implicated serovars are less virulent in general than the well-known *S. typhi*. More in favor on this last point you will see that in the review they mention that some people did develop extra-intestinal disease from reptile-derived *Salmonellas* like the man who got sinusitis, this means that if the strain is virulent enough in will cause disease even outside the gastrointestinal system.